# How to add a mouse-over event to siblings?

Tags: jquery

```
$( "#menu li" ).each(
        function(){
            $( this ).bind (
                "click",
                function(){

$(this).css("color","#FF8400");
$(this).siblings().css("color","white");


var page = $(this).attr("id");
```

In the code above, I'm trying to make the color of the link to change when clicking on it, while other links stay in white color, however these other links should have a mouse-over event that changes the color from white to #FF8400 on mouse-over. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try a combination of CSS and basic jQuery (see http://jsfiddle.net/wUgN8/)

CSS:

```
li { color: white; }
li:hover, li.on { color: #FF8400; }
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#menu li" ).bind ("click", function(){
   $("#menu li").removeClass("on");
   $(this).addClass("on");
   var page = $(this).attr("id"); });
```

Comment: BRILLIANT, That's exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( "#menu li" ).bind ("click", function(){
    $( "#menu li" ).css("color","white").removeClass("active");
    $(this).css("color","#FF8400").addClass("active");
    var page = $(this).attr("id");
    //Do Something
    .
    .
    .
})

$( "#menu li" ).hover (function(){
      var $this = $(this);
        if(!$this.hasClass("active")){
            $this.css("color","#FF8400");
      }
}, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass("active")){
       $this.css("color", "white"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but actually, this doesn't make a mouseover effect!

Comment: I have three <li> and what I'm trying to do is to make is that when the user clicks on an Li it's color turns to #FF8400, after that, if the user mouseover the other two li their color turns to #FF8400 and on mouseout it gets back to the white color, while the first clicked link is still #FF8400. and when clicking on another link the same process goes on.

Comment: @MohamedSaid let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1489/discussion-between-cybernate-and-mohamed-said)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(this).siblings().bind('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).css("color","#FF8400");
});
```

or

```
$(this).siblings().bind('mousein', function(){
    $(this).css("color","#FF8400");
}).bind('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).css("color","white");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the second code does the job, however when selecting another link after viewing the first link, the color of the second link doesn't change to #FF8400 .